# Custom UITypeEditor on ActionList / Smart Tag panel

Tags: .net, windows-forms-designer, design-time, uitypeeditor, actionlist

I have a custom UserControl with a property called ParentNode of type OptionsNode, which inherits TreeNode. My control contains a TreeView in which many of these nodes are shown during design-time. The ParentNode property is supposed to let the user select one of the nodes in the TreeView, similar to how one can select components from a dropdown in the property grid, the dropdown then shows all available components. For example, the AcceptButton property of any form shows a dropdown with all Buttons on the form to choose from.

To get this behavior in the property grid, I wrote a custom UITypeEditor for the OptionsNode class. This tells the property grid to display a dropdown, and in this dropdown I add a ListBox which is filled with a list of all nodes in the TreeView. This works just fine, the user can dropdown the 'property' and choose a node by just clicking it.

Now, after doing some more work, I implemented a custom ControlDesigner, as well as an ActionList, sometimes called Smart Tag panel. I am talking about the small popup with common properties/designer methods that pops up when you click the [>] button on the top-right of some controls (for example, the TabControl allows you to Add/Remove tabpages from there).

I have all done this before, and it is working fine. The problem now is that I want to show this same ParentNode property on the ActionList panel. So, the DesignerActionList class has a 'proxy property' that passes through the property value from the ActionList to the control and vice versa, exactly as described in the documentation as well as in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163758.aspx#S3

Code:

```
Friend Class OptionsPanelActionList
    Inherits DesignerActionList

    Public Sub New(ByVal host As OptionsPanel)
        MyBase.New(host)
    End Sub

    Public Property ParentNode As OptionsNode
        Get
            Return Me.Host.ParentNode
        End Get
        Set(value As OptionsNode)                 
            Me.SetProperty("ParentNode", value)                 
            Me.DesignerActionService.Refresh(Me.Host)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function GetSortedActionItems() As DesignerActionItemCollection
        Dim items As New DesignerActionItemCollection

        items.Add(New DesignerActionPropertyItem("ParentNode", "Parent node:", String.Empty, "Gets or sets the parent node."))

        Return items
    End Function

End Class
```

However, this does not work. The ActionList simply shows a TextBox instead of my custom UITypeEditor in the smart tag panel.

I read some more in the article I linked before (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163758.aspx#S3) and he specifically goes into this problem. His Clock control has a Face property with a FaceEditor UITypeEditor that allows people to graphically select a clock face (digital, analog or both) via a dropdown.

His solution is to simply decorate the proxy property with the Editor attribute, the same as on the original Face property.

Ok, so I tried that:

```
    <Editor(GetType(Editors.OptionsNodeEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor))> _
    Public Property ParentNode As OptionsNode
        Get
            Return Me.Host.ParentNode
        End Get
        Set(value As OptionsNode)                 
            Me.SetProperty("ParentNode", value)                 
            Me.DesignerActionService.Refresh(Me.Host)
        End Set
    End Property
```

When I open the action list window, it shows a dropdown style instead of a TextBox. Great! But as soon as I try to open the dropdown, I get an error:
"Error using the dropdown: Unable to cast object of type 'OptionsPanelActionList' to type 'OptionsPanel'"

I don't understand this error. It seems to be trying to cast an OptionsPanelActionList object to an OptionsPanel. OptionsPanel is the control that I'm designing (OptionsPanelActionList is an ActionList in the OptionsPanelDesigner, the designer for the OptionsPanel control), but I don't see how it's relevant here. I am not casting anywhere but apparently the code is doing this behind the scenes somewhere.

What am I missing? Why does my editor throw errors when trying to use a custom UITypeEditor, while the article states that it should work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

The issue was indeed a cast to OptionsPanel. It occurs in my custom UITypeEditor. I need a reference to the control (OptionsPanel) I'm editing, and found I could get it via the context.Instance property:

```
Public Overrides Function EditValue(context As System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, provider As System.IServiceProvider, value As Object) As Object
    Dim panel As OptionsPanel = DirectCast(context.Instance, OptionsPanel)
    '...
End Function
```

Apparently, when editing the property via the ActionList / Smart Tag window, the context.Instance object is not the panel but the instance of the ActionList class. So I now try to cast the Instance to OptionsPanel first, and if that fails I assume it's the ActionList class and use its Host (or Control) property to get the OptionsPanel.

Seems to work so far!